# Creating an object shows null value. How do I correctly autowire?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired

I am new to Spring. I am working on an existing application which is in SpringFramework. I have a class named Author & a method getBigImage in the Author class.

```
class Author {
    public String getBigImage()
    {
       if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(this.av))
       {
          for(Av av : this.av)
              if(av.getSize() == 136  && av.getImage() != null )
                 return av.getImage();
       }
       return null;
     }
}
```

Av class looks like this:

```
class Av {
   public String getImage() 
   {
      return image;
   }

   public void setImage(String image)
   {
       this.image=image;
   }
}
```

I am trying to access getBigImage() of the author class by creating Author object

```
          Author auth = new Author();
          auth.getBigImage();
```

But I understand that as I'm creating new auth object auth.getBigImage() would be null because it ain't set. But the whole application uses @autowired & I'm a little confused as the application is too big. In that case can you tell me what exactly should I be doing to get the Author image?

Comment: Please format your code. Also, you haven't shown us where you expect your fields to be initialized (set).

Comment: The image is set at many different places & the value comes from the API.

Comment: You should post your spring configuration ....

Answer (score 0):

As a quick fix try adding @Component annotation on top of your Author class, as shown below.

```
@Component
public class Author {
```

And then try to autowire the Author instance.

```
@Autowire
Author auth;

auth.getBigImage();
```

There is a chance this may still not work. Because your Author class should be inside the package defined to be scaned for beans. Please post your spring configuration file (xml or Java config file) if this doesn't work!